# SNS -> Lambda subscription doesn't work when set via API, but does when set by admin console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I'm setting up an SNS subscription for Lambda, using the Node `aws-sdk`. The call returns successfully - it gives me a subscription ARN, and when I look in the web console it appears. However, when I publish a message to the topic, nothing happens. I tried setting up the same subscription in the web console (all the fields look exactly the same) and it *does* work.

Is there something that the console does behind the scenes I'm not aware of? Sets permissions on the SNS topic/Lambda, anything like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out my suspicions about permissions were correct - you also need to add a `Lambda.addPermission` with the following pattern:

```
{
   FunctionName: functionArn,
   StatementId: Date.now().toString(),
   Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
   Principal: 'sns.amazonaws.com',
   SourceArn: topicArn
}
```

Comment: I've just encountered same issue. There is actually a blog post about it: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/invoking-aws-lambda-functions-via-amazon-sns/